# heroku pg:psql --app error CLI FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "hostIp", user "user name", database "Name", SSL off

Tags: windows, postgresql, heroku

I added the data base **PostgreSQL** on my **Heroku** app, I am trying to connect through CLI and `pgadmin` I getting the same error as below:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "hostIp", user "user name", database "Name", SSL off
```

I tried adding `pg_hba.conf` below entries:

```
# IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all              all                    md5

# IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

still no luck, Hope anyone can assist me in that.

Comment: `SSL off` is key there - you need to be using SSL required.

Comment: I already tried to do it in pgadmin, please see my update in the main question with screens, but same message are coming.

Comment: How did you add PostgreSQL to your application? How did you edit `pg_hba.conf`? (I don't think the default Heroku Postgres addon gives you any way to modify this file.)

Comment: What I did is, I installed PostgreSQL in my local machine and found the file (pg_hba.conf) in the root folder of the installed app, and this where I updated the entries, Please let me know what is the correct approach for doing this. @chris

Comment: postgres is running seperate to your application - that pg_hba.conf will not do anything. Are you saying that `heroku pg:psql` fails for you?

Comment: yes , it is failing with this error :psql: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer ()
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "", database "", SSL off @JohnBeynon

Comment: please open a support ticket and we can investigate further.

Comment: Done @JohnBeynon

Comment: Ok , So after openning the ticket with heroku team, they informed me that there is an issue in my local machine (Postgres installation - or Environment variable) .. I hope if anyone faced same issue can assist me in resolving this.

Answer (score -1):

For this answer, I made an assumption that you are on Windows.

---

I ran into this problem as well and soon found out that I missed an important step which is to add the binaries of the PostgreSQL to the PATH environment variable.
This is [where](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#set-up-postgres-on-windows) I found out:

> Remember to update your PATH environment variable to add the bin directory of your Postgres installation. The directory will be similar to this: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<VERSION>\bin. If you forget to update your PATH, commands like heroku pg:psql won’t work.